# Can I make subheading numbers continue after a new major heading in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

With LibreOffice section numbering enabled in `Tools` -> `Outline Numbering`, my headings and subheadings are organised like this:

## 1 First Book

### 1 First Chapter in First Book

### 2 Second Chapter in First Book

### 3 Third Chapter in First Book

## 2 Second Book

### 1 First Chapter in Second Book

And so on.

This is done with books styled as Heading 1 and Chapters as Heading 2.

The problem is I would want the above example to end up as

### 4 First Chapter in Second Book

i.e. the chapter numbers continue increasing as if they were not in separate books.

Can I do this in LibreOffice (4.3.3.2)?

The closest I've come is to make the chapters styled as Heading 1 and books styled as Heading, but that means books don't show up in the Table of Contents and also changes to the Heading style propagate into various derived styles. Perhaps both of these problems are fixable but even so this is a hack. Is there a proper way to express the numbering logic I  want?

Comment: While I don't know the answer to this, I bet some of the people who hang out at the openoffice.org forums do.  If you don't get an answer here maybe try the [Writer forum there](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewforum.php?f=7)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming books are `Heading 1` and chapters are `Heading 2`: Just disable outline numbering for level 2, and change the numbering scheme for `Heading 2` to, e.g., `Numbering 1`. To do so:

1. Menu `Tools` → `Outline and numbering`;
2. Select Level 2;
3. Disable outline numbering for this level completely:

   - set the "`Paragraph Style`" to "`[None]`", and
   - set the number to `None`:

   [image]
4. Open the `Styles and Formatting` box using <kbd>F11</kbd> or menu `Format` → `Styles and Formatting`;
5. Select the "Heading 2" paragraph style;
6. Right-click on "Heading 2" and select "Modify";

   [image]
7. On the "`Outline and Numbering`" tab, select "Level 2" as outline level and "Numbering 1" as numbering style:

   [image]

That's it. Now, if you apply the "Heading 2" style to those headings, LO Writer should continue counting the chapters. Style changes should get propagated to the different Heading styles as usual, and all Headings should appear in a TOC as usual. You may manually restart the chapter count by modifying the paragraphs style of the heading where numbering should restart.

To adapt your current document to the Heading 1/2 structure, you may use `Find & Replace` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), first replacing `Heading 1` paragraph styles with `Heading 2`, then replacing `Heading` styles with `Heading 1`.

If you need this in more than one document, repeat those steps in an empty Writer document and save it as Writer Template.

Comment: I don't have Tools -> Numbering and Outlines or Format -> Styles and Formatting menus or dialog entries. And F11 is bound to my window manager.

Comment: Menu structure has changed since 2015. Currently, it's `Tools -> Chapter Numbering` instead of `Outline Numbering`. Instead of `Format` -> `Styles and Formatting`, it's Menu `View` -> `Styles`. F11 is still the LO shortcut to open the Styles dialogue. Of course, it won't work if it's defined differently in your environment.